# Microservices FastAPI test in docker, return 404

Tags: python, docker, microservices, pytest, fastapi

I created a simple library project in microservices to study and implement FastAPI.
Docker starts 5 main services:

- books
- db-book
- author
- db-author
- nginx

Everything works as expected, making requests with postman I have no problem.

#### Structure

[image: structure]

### Problem description

I added a test directory where I test endpoints.

#### Example of (incomplete) author test

```py
from starlette.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app
from app.api.author import authors
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('__name__')
import requests

client = TestClient(app)

def test_get_authors():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200

def test_get_author():
    response = client.get("/1")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

`$> docker-compose exec author_service pytest .`  
returns this

```py
============================================================================================================= test session starts =============================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-5.3.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /app
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

tests/test_author.py FF                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [100%]

================================================================================================================== FAILURES ===================================================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_get_authors _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_get_authors():
        response = client.get("/")
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 404 == 200
E        +  where 404 = <Response [404]>.status_code

tests/test_author.py:12: AssertionError
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_get_author _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_get_author():
        response = client.get("/1")
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 404 == 200
E        +  where 404 = <Response [404]>.status_code

tests/test_author.py:16: AssertionError
============================================================================================================== 2 failed in 0.35s ==============================================================================================================
```

I tried to start the tests directly from the container shell but nothing the same.
This problem occurs only with tests that are done following the documentation (using starlette / fastapi) and with requests

You can find the complete project here
[Library Microsrevices example](https://gitlab.com/Plaoo/library-microservices-example)

#### Environment

- OS:[Linux Fedora 32]
- FastAPI Version [0.55.1]:
- Python: [Python 3.8.3]

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  book_service:
    build: ./book-service
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./book-service/:/app/
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URI=postgresql://book_db_username:book_db_password@book_db/book_db_dev
      - AUTHOR_SERVICE_HOST_URL=http://author_service:8000/api/v1/authors/
    depends_on:
      - book_db

  book_db:
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_book:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=book_db_username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=book_db_password
      - POSTGRES_DB=book_db_dev
  
  author_service:
    build: ./author-service
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./author-service/:/app/
    ports:
      - 8002:8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URI=postgresql://author_db_username:author_db_password@author_db/author_db_dev
    depends_on:
      - author_db

  author_db:
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_author:/var/lib/postgres/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=author_db_username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=author_db_password
      - POSTGRES_DB=author_db_dev

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_config.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - author_service
      - book_service

volumes:
  postgres_data_book:
  postgres_data_author:
```

Comment: Please add here your docker-compose file? How is your network declared?

Comment: @abestrad added docker-compose

Comment: Hi @Sanjiv I don't understand how this guide can help me. It absolutely does not talk about how to set up docker to run the tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using docker0 network ip address and with requests. Tests can now be started using 172.13.0.1 on port 8080

Answer (score -1):

the main problem here are your endpoints on test file

**Test example fixed:**

```py
from starlette.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app
from app.api.author import authors
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('__name__')
import requests

client = TestClient(app)

def test_get_authors():
    response = client.get("/authors") # this must be your API endpoint to test
    assert response.status_code == 200

def test_get_author():
    response = client.get("/authors/1") # this must be your API endpoint to test 
    assert response.status_code == 200
```